# What is this command prompt code in MacOS?

Tags: macos

I know this code works on Windows, but how do I get workable code executable on MacOS?

> netsh -c interface ipv4 add neighbors "(connection name)" "(router
>   address)" "(mac address)" store=persistent

Any suggestions please...

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and [ask]. You're not asking a programming question but one about network administration, which makes your question unsuitable here. Consider e.g. superuser.com, but make sure you read the site rules there first.

Answer (score 0):

try typing "man arp" into the terminal.  Something like this might work :

```
arp -s hostname ether_addr
             Create an ARP entry for the host called hostname with the Ethernet address ether_addr.  The Ethernet address is
             given as six hex bytes separated by colons.  The entry will be permanent unless the word temp is given in the
             command.  If the word pub is given, the entry will be ``published''; i.e., this system will act as an ARP server,
             responding to requests for hostname even though the host address is not its own.  In this case the ether_addr can
             be given as auto in which case the interfaces on this host will be examined, and if one of them is found to
             occupy the same subnet, its Ethernet address will be used.  If the only keyword is also specified, this will cre-
             ate a ``published (proxy only)'' entry.  This type of entry is created automatically if arp detects that a rout-
             ing table entry for hostname already exists.
```